# Why is this a solution to the ODE system

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of differential equations $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu$ where $x,B \in \mathbb R^n$, $A \in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ and $u \in \mathbb R$, we want to find a solution.

I was given a solution of the form $x(t)=e^{At}x(0)+\int_{0}^{t}e^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau$. I'm just wondering why is this a solution? if we derive it, we don't seem to get $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x(t)=e^{At}x(0)+e^{At}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-A\tau}Bu(\tau)d\tau$$

$$\dot x(t)=Ae^{At}x(0)+Ae^{At}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-A\tau}Bu(\tau)d\tau +e^{At}e^{-At}Bu(t)$$

$$=Ax(t) +Bu(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, just managed this myself too. Still upvoted and accepted as answer. Thank you!